# How to print HTML section using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, html5-canvas

I am using html2Canvas.js to convert HTML element to canvas and then converting canvas to image makes it browser comaptible for printing, is this the correct approach for printing HTML? I find image is the best to way to get similar print in any printer.

Comment: Is there any way I can see preview or modify the HTML and save the state?

Comment: The best practice would be to créate au `@media print` `css` more simple

Comment: Maybe it can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript function for print

```
<div onlick='window.print()'>Print</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add this code to your css:

```
.toPrint {
  display:none;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@media print {
   * {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .toPrint {
    display: block !important;
  }

}
```

And use this code when you want the print view updated:

```
/** code borrowed from @MicrosoftGoogle */
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

if (document.getElementsByClassName("toPrint")) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("toPrint")[0].src = img;
else
  document.write('<img class="toPrint" src="'+img+'"/>');
```